# Is there any easier way to convert a string that looks like a list in DuckDB than regexp_split_to_array or string_split?

Tags: duckdb

I am attempting to query a Pandas Dataframe with DuckDB that I materialize with [read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html).

Some of this data is stored in a JSON format and in the target column each value has a list of items - ["Value1", "Value2", "Valueetc"] that from the point of view of DuckDB is just a VARCHAR column.

My goal was to convert the string that looks like a list to an actual list in the DDB context -

```
STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ColumnName, '"',''),'[',''),']',''),',') AS ColumnName
```

I can definitely remove the quotes and brackets and return a list with this approach but I was hoping there's a less ugly/more idiomatic way to accomplish the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is easier! First, just load the JSON extension like in these docs:
https://duckdb.org/docs/extensions/json
Then try this: (untested!)

```sql
Select
  from_json(
    json(ColumnName),
    '["VARCHAR"]'
  ) as my_list
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems slightly more elegant

```
select (regexp_split_to_array('["Value1", "Value2", "Valueetc"]','", "|\["|"\]'))[2:-1];
```

This returns a list of three string values

```
[Value1, Value2, Valueetc]
```

Regex should probably be made more robust wrt spaces and such